# how to add my custom template of heatbeat

Tags: 7, heartbeat

d7+heratbeat version = "7.x-1.1"

I have a module named "love.module"
in love.module

```
/**
 * Implement hook_ctools_plugin_api().
 *
 * This hook is needed to let ctools know about exportables.
 * @see heartbeat_og_ctools_plugin_api
 */
function love_ctools_plugin_api($module, $api) {
  if ($module == 'love' && $api == 'love') {
    return array('version' => 1);
  }
}
```

and I have a file name love.heartbeat.inc,

```
    <?php
/**
 * Implements hook_heartbeat_template_info().
 */
function love_heartbeat_template_info() {
  watchdog('-call', 'message', array(), WATCHDOG_NOTICE, 'link');
$heartbeatmessagetemplate = new HeartbeatMessageTemplate();
$heartbeatmessagetemplate->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default heartbeatmessagetemplate disabled initially */
$heartbeatmessagetemplate->api_version = 1;
$heartbeatmessagetemplate->message_id = 'heartbeat_add_comment2';
$heartbeatmessagetemplate->description = 'user replied on some content';
$heartbeatmessagetemplate->message = '<span>!username replied on !title:</span><blockquote><div>!comment</div></blockquote>';
$heartbeatmessagetemplate->message_concat = '%username% replied on !title.';
$heartbeatmessagetemplate->perms = 2;
$heartbeatmessagetemplate->group_type = 'summary';
$heartbeatmessagetemplate->concat_args = array(
  'group_by' => 'node',
  'group_target' => 'username',
  'group_by_target' => 'title',
  'group_num_max' => '5',
  'merge_separator' => ', ',
  'merge_end_separator' => ' and ',
  'roles' => array(
    1 => 0,
    2 => 0,
    3 => 0,
    4 => 0,
    5 => 0,
  ),
);
$heartbeatmessagetemplate->variables = array(
  '!username' => '',
  '!title' => '',
  '!comment' => '',
);
$heartbeatmessagetemplate->attachments = array(
  'buttons' => array(
    'weight' => array(
      'activitycomments' => '-9',
      'flagattachment:like' => '0',
    ),
    'settings' => array(
      'activitycomments' => array(
        'activitycomments_node' => 0,
      ),
    ),
    'enabled' => array(
      'activitycomments' => 0,
      'flagattachment:like' => 0,
    ),
  ),
  'content' => array(
    'weight' => array(
      'activitycomments' => '-9',
      'flagattachment:like' => '0',
    ),
    'enabled' => array(
      'activitycomments' => 0,
      'flagattachment:like' => 0,
    ),
  ),
);


  return $heartbeatmessagetemplate;
}
```

but the hook didn't called.who can help me?
did I miss somthing?

Comment: Can you please post your module info file as well, .inc files should be included in there.

Comment: Have you found the solution for this issue? I have the same problem here. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and what you should do is replace

```
/**
 * Implement hook_ctools_plugin_api().
 *
 * This hook is needed to let ctools know about exportables.
 * @see heartbeat_og_ctools_plugin_api
 */
function love_ctools_plugin_api($module, $api) {
  if ($module == 'love' && $api == 'love') {
    return array('version' => 1);
  }
}
```

by

```
/**
 * Implement hook_ctools_plugin_api().
 *
 * This hook is needed to let ctools know about exportables.
 * @see heartbeat_og_ctools_plugin_api
 */
function love_ctools_plugin_api($module, $api) {
  if ($module == 'heartbeat' && $api == 'heartbeat') {
    return array('version' => 1);
  }
}
```

and after a cache flush, it should appear in heartbeat templates